# How do I view the compiled SQL query in AIR?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, sqlite, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to run a query in SQL using parameters, but getting error message "could not convert text value to numeric value".

The error's not important in this question. I'd be able to fix it if I were just able to view the final compiled SQL query that AIR builds using all of the parameters.

Not having any luck finding how I can do this. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `statement.toString()`? I don't know whether it outputs the translated statement, just guessing here.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no function that can do that. The SQLStatement class has a 'text' property that you can use to trace the query, but the 'text' property won't display the actual value for a parameter (e.g., if mySqlStatement is "SELECT col1 FROM Table1 WHERE col2 = :someNumber", mySqlStatement.text won't show you the actual value for :someNumber). It wouldn't be that difficult to create an AS3 function that replaces any parameters in mySqlStatement.text with the actual value(s) in mySqlStatement.parameters (i.e., any word that begins with colon or is a question mark) and then traces the result.

Answer (score -1):

How about simply tracing out the SQL statement. You will be able to see any variable values in the output.

e.g.

```
trace("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='"+ _variable +"'");
```